# ARCore : Augmented Image and barcode recognizing android

Tags: android, image-processing, augmented-reality, barcode-scanner, arcore

I want to create an app that scans a barcode on a box and show some information on the box with augmented reality!
Scandit creates this but I want to create my own ones.
I read some articles and I think that I can use Augmented Image for recognizing barcode paper on the box,  I need to access bitmap of Augmented Image after that I can read the barcode in it.

Here is my question:

How can I access the bitmap of the recognized image in Augmented Image?
(and if you know another way for doing this please suggest me)
Thanks :)

Comment: Why does it have to be a barcode. You can create an augmented image database and each image has a name and index. I mean if what you want is to find a way to differentiate images and show information related to only that image.

Comment: @alikanat as I wrote I have to read a barcode on products :)

Answer (score -2):

A suggestion : You can use any barcode image reading library to parse the data from barcode present on actual object instead of using the augmented image for this purpose

Then, you can use a rendered layout and position it on the flat surface of the object.

So, there will be 2 steps.
1) Reading barcode data (no AR involved)
2) Displaying a rendered layout on the box(object) according to data (AR part)

Here is a link to demonstrate creating a renderable from layout : https://www.yudiz.com/sceneform-sdk-a-boon-for-android-developers/